# Maven project doesn't put files in src/main/resources on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I have a java project in Eclipse. I want a read file that is in a certain folder. I use this code:

```
File file = new File("directory/filename.txt");
```

If I have a simple java project, with this layout:

```
Project
|
+- src
+- lib
+- directory
   |
   + filename.text
```

The code works fine and I can read the file. If I now convert this project to a maven project, Not much changes in Eclipse except a pom.xml file is made and a target folder is added (revaling the previously hidden "bin" output folder which is now a regular folder. The layout becomes:

```
Project
|
+- src
+- lib
+- bin
+- target
+- directory
|  |
|  + filename.text
+- pom.xml
```

Because I want to use the maven project setup, I removed the src folder and added 4 new source folders to my project in Eclipse:

[image: Source folders]

I copied the `filename.text` to the resources folder, which should automaticcaly put its content on the classpath. My project layout becomes:

```
Project
|
+- src/main/java
+- src/main/resources
|   |
|   + filename.text
+- src/test/java
+- src/test/resources
+- lib
+- bin
+- target
+- pom.xml
```

Now I noticed that this code doesn't work (NoSuchFileException)

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
```

But this code does work:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/filename.txt");
```

Note: the way I run my code is by running it in eclipse as a java project. The file read code is a single line in my main method in my main class.

I'm wondering what configuration I missed so that eclipse/maven regards the src/main/resources folder to be at the root of my classpath, rather than just a random folder that I have to explicitly name. It's especially weird, because another file in the resources folder, namely log4j.properties, is found and used by my log4j library without any problems.

Note: If I build my project and install it in my local repository, I can actually see both files (filename.txt and log4j.properties) being neatly under target/classes.

Comment: If you want to read a file from the classpath you must use it as a resource. If you want to read it from the filesystem you must provide an actual path.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: @ Dave Newton: How do I use a file as a resource?

Answer (score 0):

On your project:

**Right-Click > Properties > Java build Path > Source** : if you have some thing like :

[image]
**Right-Click > Properties > Deployement Assembly** : check if you have some thing like:

[image]

Hope this helps.